# QGIS - Combining contours without elevation and point elevation data

Tags: qgis, dem, contour

I have a geopackage (Ordnance Survey Terrain 50) that has two layers: a layer with contours but no elevation data, and a layer of point elevation data.

I'd like to create a DEM. The technique I've found requires contours that have elevation data. How do I combine the two layers in QGIS to give me this?

Comment: Ususally you can interpolate a DEM from point data (`TIN` or `IDW-interpolation`). Depending on the spacing of the points you may come up with a relatively low resolution.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create a DEM from the contours and spot heights, you can download the DEM directly. Select "ASCII Grid and GML (Grid): 162 Mb" on the [OS Terrain® 50 download page](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html#TERR50).

[image]

If you really want to interpolate from the contours and spot heights... The contours *do* contain elevation. As per the [user guide](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/documents/os-terrain-50-user-guide.pdf), the elevation of each contour is stored in the `propertyValue` attribute:

> The draft INSPIRE elevation specification requires height values to be
>   held in an attribute called ‘propertyValue’

[image]

Comment: That's very helpful. Thanks.